# How to create tile wallpaper in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I am trying to make tile wallpaper in flex. I did stretch or normal use the backgroundSize as 100% and "auto". But i have no idea about how to create tile.

Can someone help me with source, instruction or the best would be a source code.

Regards
Zeeshan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating a tiled backgound in Flex 3 is not available through the use of of CSS styles or property styles.

However it is possible simply by assigning your component a custom programmatic skin, which handles the drawing of the tiled image through using the raw bitmap data.

Let me further illustrate my point with some code

```
<mx:Canvas borderSkin="{TiledBackgroundSkin}"
    width="100%" height="100%">
</mx:Canvas>
```

That is your component with a programmatic border skin applied to it.

Now you just create that border skin by extending the RectangularBorder class.
Such as:

```
public class TiledBackgroundSkin extends RectangularBorder
{
    [Bindable]      
    [Embed(source='tile.jpg')]
    private var tileImageClass  :Class;
    private var tileBitmapData  :BitmapData;

    public function TiledBackgroundSkin()
    {
        super(); 
        createBitmap()
    }

    /** A private method that handles the drawing of the bitmap **/
    private function createBitmap():void
    {
        var backgroundImage:Bitmap = new tileImageClass();
        tileBitmapData = new BitmapData(backgroundImage.width,backgroundImage.height);
        tileBitmapData.draw( backgroundImage );
    }

    /** Override updateDisplayList to draw the Tiled Background **/
    override protected function updateDisplayList(  unscaledWidth:Number,unscaledHeight:Number ):void 
    {
        super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth,unscaledHeight );
        graphics.clear();
        graphics.beginBitmapFill( tileBitmapData );
        graphics.drawRect(0,0,unscaledWidth,unscaledHeight);
        graphics.endFill();
    }       
}
```

The constructor creates the bitmap image for tiling.

Then the updateDisplayList method *(called after initial creation and for subsequent resizes of the component)* fills the entire component with the tiled background.

If you wish to adjust the offset positioning of the tiled image, you would do so in the updateDisplayList method